# What does this phrase mean? "l'accolade l'est beaucoup moins"

Tags: sens, pronoms

I saw this phrase I can't understand:

> Si la bise est une pratique courante entre amis, l'accolade l'est beaucoup moins.

Specially the part "l'accolade l'est" since I have never seen `l'est` before or what it even means, I can't understand the whole sentence.

Comment: *L'* is a pronoun that stands for "pratique courante", (l'accolade est une pratique beaucoup moins courante que la bise).

Comment: it means "hugging is much less common though'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll combine the two points from the comments since neither user decided to propose an answer.

---

#### l'est

The *l'est* here is the usual direct object pronoun (*le*, *la*, and so on) followed by the verb.

> Tu manges mon gâteau ?!
>   
> → Oui, je le mange ... *[le = le gâteau]*

If you haven't encountered this yet, you could read up on the subject "French direct object pronouns". I did a quick Google search and found a few primers on it, and [this one](http://www.dummies.com/languages/french/how-to-use-french-direct-object-pronouns/) looks pretty good.

These words can also replace the object of *être*, as *le* does here:

> Tu n'es pas français donc ?
>   
> → Mais si ... je le suis ! *[le = français]*

Grammatically, this is the exact same as *le* or *la* before any other verb. The usual translation would be "it" if replacing a thing, "him" or "her" if replacing a person, or "so" if replacing an adjective.

**It's true, though, that this can sound strange in English** because we tend to omit the direct object after "to be", as in these examples:

> Est-elle la meurtrière ? *Is she the murderer?*
>   
> → Oui ... elle l'est ! *Yes... she is!* (literally "she is her / she is it")
>   
> → Mais non, je la suis ! *No, I am!* (literally "I am her / I am it")

But in French you can rarely leave out *le*, *la*, *l'*. (That can also be seen at the end of [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25387/how-to-differentiate-between-me-as-a-direct-object-and-as-indirect-object/25389#25389).)

So this is what's happening in your sentence:

> Si la bise est une pratique courante entre amis, l'accolade **l**'est beaucoup moins.
>   
> → While kissing on the cheeks is a common practice among friends, hugging is much less **so**.

---

#### What's replaced?

This section is overkill for your question, but read on if you're interested.

There's arguably more than one thing that *l'* could have been intended to mean here. If it refers to *une pratique courante*, we would probably expect to see a phrase with *en ... une* ("one of those") instead. If it refers to just the adjective *courante*, the reader has to implicitly extract that from the noun phrase *une pratique courante*.

In the absence of that clue, I believe *courant(e)* is what's replaced, which is why I translated it "much less *so*" instead of "much less *one*". The reason I land on this side is that it would seem strange to me to make the jump from an indefinite complement (*une pratique courante*) to a definite pronoun (*le/la*).

*Edit:* The consensus below is that this reading is correct: *l'* here replaces the adjective *courant(e)*. However, in older or literary French, as Feelew's sources suggest, an indefinite noun phrase could apparently be replaced by a definite object pronoun.

Another question is whether this *l'* would be *le* or *la* if it weren't before a vowel (for example, in the *futur simple* and *passé simple* tenses). Common usage today would probably be a "neutral" masculine *le* when replacing the adjective, and even when replacing the noun if that's still possible, whereas in older/literary French a feminine agreement with either one seems to have been thinkable.

Comment: Hmm you are right about the ambiguity - but it's the kind of thing we never think about :-)

Comment: You show a good example of the use of le/la I know these In some cases they can also be `l'` with apostrophe provided the next word begins with a vowel, but my question was more of why `l` is added with `est`, if `est` I understand the need to remove whatever vowel (a,e) comes after `l` since we can't say `le est` or `la est`, but generally what does it even mean `l'est`? My mind tries to create a meaning that sounds like `the is` because I have never read that before

Comment: @meskerem Ah, I think I've got the issue. You'd usually translate *l'est* as "is it", "is him", or "is her". In English you'd usually end the sentence at "is".  (Notice: There's no connection with "the" even though it looks the same! Read up on the direct object pronoun till you're comfortable with that.) I've tried to clear the question up more in my new edit, so let me know if it's helpful or not.

Comment: @Frank Fair enough :p But even if you don't think about it, you might use it sometimes. Riddle me this: If you were making a prediction about the future of hugging, would you say *le sera* or *la sera* here?

Comment: If it is what you mean, *elle sera courante → elle **la** sera* is grammatically impossible, should be *elle **le** sera*.

Comment: Indeed - the *la* option here would refer to *la pratique*, as mentioned in my answer (which I lean away from since the specimen is *une pratique*).

Comment: Correct - if you use _la_, you refer to _pratique_, but it would be very strange as is, you would need to manipulate the sentence somewhat to make it work.

Comment: It is indeed _courante_ that's being replaced. If we look at a simple past version, we quickly realize that _‘a much less practice’_ is a very strange encounter: «Si la bise fut une pratique courante entre amis, l'accolade la fut beaucoup moins.»

Comment: Whatever *l'* refers to, it can't be but *le*. Last @feelew 's sentence is not only strange but incorrect. The right one should be *Si la bise fut une pratique courante entre amis, l'accolade **le** fut beaucoup moins*. The neutral pronoun *le* must be used when referring to a noun introduced by an indefinite article so it can't agree with *pratique* even when it refers to it.

Comment: Well... Obviously my sentence was incorrect. It was so blatantly incorrect that I thought using _strange_ as a euphemism would be perfectly transparent. After all, humans tend to find strange incorrectly composed statements, and strangeness can often come as one of the first clues that lead into claiming something is incorrect. A _‘much less practice’_ was also a very strange English statement... I’ll leave the last word to Marot and his sublime verse ‘Roi le plus roi qui fut onc couronné’.

Comment: My question is: Can it refer to a noun introduced by an indefinite article at all? (That is interesting about the gender if so, but incidental to my concern.) Would you accept "La Terre est une planète ; Jupiter l'est aussi" , or would it have to be "Jupiter en est une" or similar? I've removed the adjective here to eliminate the possibility that the direct object pronoun's reference reaches into the NP and selects the adjective. But which would be stranger when both are present: its doing so or its referring to an indefinite NP?

Comment: 2 examples from _Le bon usage_, showing two different approaches, great authors for both: «Je n'étais ta maîtresse qu'ici; à présent je LA serai partout» — «Vos sujets? Ils ne LE sont plus». These two have nouns that are definite to start with, though. With _une_ as in your example, I am not sure. I’ll keep searching.

Comment: Found it. Unless it is representing a noun preceded by a definite article or by a possessive, demonstrative, or interrogative determinant, we shall use a neutral _LE_: «Ma sœur est une enfant, –et je ne LE suis plus» (Musset). Historically, and up to the 18th century, it could vary: «Vous êtes satisfaite et je ne LA suis pas» (Corneille) — with a noun (arguably): «J'étais née, moi, pour être sage, et je LA suis devenue».(Beaumarchais)

Comment: Nice citations!

Comment: Incorporated with a tentative tone into a new edit; if there are any more disagreements on the subject I'll just make it a new question and invite various answers, since I think we've outgrown this one. :)